# How can I obtain the BundleWiring of the calling Bundle in OSGi?

Tags: java, liferay, osgi, liferay-7, wab

I have an active bundle called `bundleA` which implements a class called `Example` with a method called `doSomething()` from another bundle. `ExampleImpl` implements `Example` and is loaded via [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) (thanks to [SPI Fly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html)). In `ExampleImpl.doSomething()` from `bundleA`, I need to get the `BundleWiring` of the bundle which called `doSomething()` (without passing the `Bundle` or `BundleContext` since I cannot change the API). I can get `bundleA`'s `BundleWiring`, but not the calling bundle's `BundleWiring`:

```
Bundle bundleA = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ExampleClass.class);
BundleWiring bundleWiringOfBundleA = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
```

How can I obtain the calling bundle's `BundleWiring`?

In my particular case, the calling bundle will always be a WAB which happens to be running in [Liferay Portal 7.0](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7.0.x). So if there's a solution specific to Liferay Portal, I would accept that, but a more general OSGi solution would be fine as well.

Note that I want the **calling bundle's bundle wiring** not the bundle wiring of every bundle that depends on the current bundle wiring. I know that I can obtain the bundle wirings that are dependent on the current bundle wiring, but that won't help me obtain the calling bundle specifically:

```
Bundle bundleA = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ExampleClass.class);
List<BundleWires> bundleWires =
    bundleWiring.getProvidedWires(BundleRevision.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE);
bundleWires.get(0).getRequirerWiring();
```

Comment: Why do you need the BundleWiring?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, I want to get the `BundleWiring` of the WAB (or calling bundle) so I can find all of the bundles that the WAB depends on. I want to find all the dependencies so I can find certain files and annotated classes in the dependencies. I'm working with some jars that are technically OSGi bundles, but they are not really set up for an OSGi environment. So I'm trying to see if I can make it work without rewriting everything to be OSGi friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Liferay, the calling WAB's `BundleContext` is stored in the `ServletContext` as `"osgi-bundlecontext"`:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = servletContext.getAttribute("osgi-bundlecontext");
Bundle bundle = bundleContext.getBundle();
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
```

So as long as you have access to the `ServletContext` in Liferay you can obtain the calling bundle's `Bundle` and `BundleWiring`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this. OSGi does not intervene at all in cross-bundle method invocation, so the only thing you can possibly use to try to get this information is the Java call stack, accessed with `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`. However the `StackTraceElement` objects that this returns only gives you class names not `java.lang.Class` objects, so there is no way to correlate those back to bundles.

Besides being impossible, I'm very skeptical that this would ever be a good idea. You shouldn't export implementation classes at all, let alone try to make them caller-sensitive.

If you need to implement behaviour that is sensitive to the calling bundle then the canonical and correct way to achieve that is to register a service using the `ServiceFactory` interface.

Comment: Whoops, you are right, I'm not exporting the `ExampleImpl`, duh. I've edited the question.

Comment: Okay but now it's not clear how the calling bundle gets hold of ExampleImpl. Is it registered as a service?

Comment: Yeah, `ExampleImpl` is loaded via `ServiceLoader` with SPI Fly.

Comment: Oh then it's not a service... that's a shame. Then my original answer stands: you can't do what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [BundleTracker](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html) and react on all WABs being installed. Then you can introspect each WAB and for example scan classes for annotations.

Declarative services and the existing WAB support work this way. Writing such an extender is not easy though.

Answer (score -1):

You said you can't change the API. But can you change the calling bundles? If so, then you could have a "proxy" service that calling bundles use instead of the original one. You can then pass `Bundle` and/or `BundleContext` to the proxy service and put your dependency logic there.

Another option that comes to mind is using `ThreadLocal` variables to pass this information to the called bundle, but I'm not sure about what side effects that approach may have.